# Get the attribute of NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey of the file

Tags: ios, objective-c

To exclude files from backups to iCloud and iTunes, I have used the code below :

```
BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]

                              forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
```

The value of the success is YES, but I still want to check the corresponding attribute of the file. I try to use the code below, but it fails:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[URL valueForKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey]);
```

what is the right way to achieve my purpose? thanks!

Comment: Have you not tried getResourceValue method? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/getResourceValue:forKey:error:

Comment: @Shashank No.I think it may work. But,   How to set the fisrt two parameters for this function?

Answer (score 0):

As Shashank suggested, if you're setting a resource value via `setResourceValue`, you need to access it via `getResourceValue`. `valueForKey` is for KVC, and is not related to resource values.

In order to do this, you need to pass in the object you want to hold the result in.

```
NSNumber* backupKeyResult = nil;
NSError* error = nil;

BOOL result = [URL getResourceValue:&result forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:&error];

if (result && !error) {
   if (backupKeyResult) {
       BOOL backupKeySet = [backupKeyResult boolValue];
       // backupKeySet has the value you've set previously
   }
   else {
        // The requested resource value is not defined for the URL.
   }
}
else {
    if (error) {
        // An error occurred whilst trying this, check your NSError object to see what's up
    }
    else if (!result) {
        // The value was not successfully populated
    }
}
```